# Should this weird question be closed, and for what reason?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

This question could easily be closed as too localized on old close logic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352878/android-help-search-pdf-etc

However since I've not acclimated to new close logic, I'm not sure which reason it would fall under, or if it's suddenly a valid question instead.  It currently has one vote as "unclear what you're asking," which is wrong - it's very clear what the OP is asking. It's just... *wrong*. Or maybe not, now.

Comment: It's offtpoic, which is what the existing votes are primarily for.

Comment: I went with Off Topic > Other. I guess we'll find out if I'm right or not. <shrug>

Comment: @Servy It's about programming though.

Comment: Isnt it devistatingly off topic?

Comment: @djechlin it isn't about programming at all. It's about buying a programming book, or perhaps finding the author of a programming book.

Comment: @djechlin: Just because a question mentions programming in some way does not make it on-topic. That's why we have that part at the end that says "within the scope defined in the help center." *Scope* is the key.

Comment: @djechlin [My favorite programming cartoon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) isn't a programming question, despite the fact that I'm a programmer, or that the cartoon may include programming-related humor.

Comment: It's not about programming, and neither is coffee that I drink to keep me awake while I'm programming.

Comment: @Servy (ignoring the lock because it spoils my point) the link to exactly the question you describe as being not good on stackoverflow doesnt help your case

Comment: FWIW I edited it to sound vaguely intelligible.  Help center includes tools used by programmers, I would say books are in the spirit of this.  Most book recommendation questions are opinion-based but this one isn't. I think it's actually on topic if we follow the letter.

Comment: Never use the letter of the law to subvert the spirit of the law

Comment: @RichardTingle but the spirit of the law has changed with the overhaul. And I see a real case that this is on topic. And if it's not, then, this should go over to the "close overhaul" end user feedback team.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Stack overflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on topic is defined as

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming
  profession

While finding an author of a programming book, is a problem and is related to programming I don't think it would be called a programming problem. If you bought a book on programming problems you would be very surprised to find it there.

So the question is off topic

Comment: It's been deleted in the mean time.

Comment: @Cole The system works